# VSCode Intellisense: c_cpp_properties.json Cannot Find Certain Folders

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include-path

I am current working on VSCode 1.78.2 with C/C++ extension, and I want to include libappindicator/app-indicator.h from appindicator3-0.1.

To make sure Intellisense work, I ran `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 appindicator3-0.1` and pasted the paths into the `includePath` of c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "env": {
        "myDefaultIncludePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}",
            "${workspaceFolder}/include"
        ],
        "myCompilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/g++"
    },
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "include paths",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/libappindicator3-0.1/",
                "/usr/include/libdbusmenu-glib-0.4/",
                "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
                "/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0",
                "/usr/include/at-spi-2.0",
                "/usr/include/dbus-1.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include",
                "/usr/include/gtk-3.0",
                "/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/pango-1.0",
                "/usr/include/fribidi",
                "/usr/include/harfbuzz",
                "/usr/include/atk-1.0",
                "/usr/include/cairo",
                "/usr/include/pixman-1",
                "/usr/include/uuid",
                "/usr/include/freetype2",
                "/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "/usr/include/libpng16",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
                "/usr/include/libmount",
                "/usr/include/blkid",
                "/usr/include/glib-2.0",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

However, while the paths associated with gtk worked as expected, VSCode reported two problems 'Cannot find "/usr/include/libappindicator3-0.1/".' and 'Cannot find "/usr/include/libappindicator3-0.1/".'.

I am certain that the two paths are valid, since a) they show up on my file browser, b) the program builds and runs just fine from command line.

I tried different ways to express the paths, and adding "/*" or "/**" to them, but they do not seem to have an effect.

Comment: when you paste those paths into your file explorer or pass them to an `ls` command call in a shell, do those work as expected?

Comment: @starball Curiously, the problematic paths will only work with `ls` on my system's terminal, but not on the VSCode's terminal. They show up just fine on my fiele explorer.

Comment: weird. does that path have any symlinks in it? what shell is your system terminal? what shell are you using in the VS Code integrated terminal?

Comment: @starball my system terminal shell is /bin/bash, and the VS Code terminal is /bin/sh (even when I choose the "bash" option whenc creating a new terminal instance in VS Code, `echo $SHELL` still gives me /bin/sh)